# I am trying to send HTTPS request in restful webservice and getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl

Below code is working fine for HTTP request but not for HTTPS. I am getting this error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

The URL with HTTPS is working fine when I send the request via `hurl.it`. Is there a client builder for https requests?

Here is my code :

```
HttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpRequestBase baseRequest = null;
        String apiResponse = null;
        try {
            httpClient = getClientConnection(url, clientConfiguration.isProxyEnabled());
            baseRequest = getHttpClient(url, clientConfiguration.getRequestMethod());

            if (headers != null) {
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                    baseRequest.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            if (!clientConfiguration.getRequestMethod().equals(RequestMethod.GET)) {
                // checking for post body parameters
                if (clientConfiguration.getURLParameters() != null
                        && !clientConfiguration.getURLParameters().isEmpty()) {
                    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    for (Entry<String, String> param : clientConfiguration.getURLParameters().entrySet()) {
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(param.getKey(), param.getValue()));
                    }
                    if (baseRequest instanceof HttpPost) {
                        ((HttpPost) baseRequest).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
                    } else if (baseRequest instanceof HttpPut) {
                        ((HttpPut) baseRequest).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
                    } else if (baseRequest instanceof CoreDelete) {
                        ((CoreDelete) baseRequest).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("URL " + url);
            if (clientConfiguration.getRequestBody() != null) {
                HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(clientConfiguration.getRequestBody().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                if (baseRequest instanceof HttpPost) {
                    ((HttpPost) baseRequest).setEntity(entity);
                } else if (baseRequest instanceof HttpPut) {
                    ((HttpPut) baseRequest).setEntity(entity);
                } else if (baseRequest instanceof CoreDelete) {
                    ((CoreDelete) baseRequest).setEntity(entity);
                }
            }
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(baseRequest);
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html

Comment: Does your service endpoint have a valid HTTPS certificate and is it configured properly ?

Comment: Do I need to configure HTTPS certificate on my local system? How?